# Passing an array in an Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand parameter hash table not working

Tags: arrays, azure, powershell, hashtable, azure-runbook

I am trying to execute an Azure Automation Account PowerShell runbook which shall execute a PowerShell script on an Azure Win VM using the following statement:

```
Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $sdvobjVM1.ResourceGroupName -Name $sdvstrNameVM1 -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $sdvstrScriptFileNameTmp -Parameter $sdvhshParamsFolderCopy
```

The statement's parameter is as follows:

```
$sdvhshParamsFolderCopy = @{Para1='String1'; Para2='String2'; Para3='String3'; Para4='String4'; Para5='String5'; Para6=@('Application', 'Data', 'Execution')}
```

**Question:** Is this possible with the embedded array ("Para6") in the hash table? And if yes, how?

I have tried this for some time now without success as I cannot access the array values in the remote script; see below for details and actual code samples. Please someone help!!!

Problem details:

In the Azure Automation runbook I have:

...

```
[string] $sdvstrFileShare = "$sdvstrNameSA1.file.core.windows.net\$sdvstrFileShareName"
[array] $sdvastrCopyFolders = @('Application', 'Data', 'Execution')
```

...

```
$sdvhshParamsFolderCopy = @{sdvstrNameSA1 = $sdvstrNameSA1;
                            sdvstrSA1AccessKey = $sdvstrSA1AccessKey;
                            sdvstrFileShare = $sdvstrFileShare;
                            sdvstrSrcDriveLetter = $sdvstrSrcDriveLetter;
                            sdvstrDstDriveLetter = $sdvstrDstDriveLetter;
                            sdvastrCopyFolders = $sdvastrCopyFolders
    }
```

(break-line grave-accents removed here)

In the invoked script I have:

```
# Parameters
Param (
    [string] $sdvstrNameSA1,
    [string] $sdvstrSA1AccessKey,
    [string] $sdvstrFileShare,      
    [string] $sdvstrSrcDriveLetter,
    [string] $sdvstrDstDriveLetter,     
    [array] $sdvastrCopyFolders
)
```

Both [array] $sdvastrCopyFolders and [array[]] $sdvastrCopyFolders won't work.

The symptom is that I am getting in the invoked script:

```
$sdvastrCopyFolders | ForEach{$_} | Out-File  -FilePath 'D:\sdvastrCopyFoldersForEach.txt'
System.Object[]

$sdvastrCopyFolders.Item(0) | Out-File  -FilePath 'D:\sdvastrCopyFoldersItem0.txt'
System.Object[]

$sdvastrCopyFolders.GetValue(0) | Out-File  -FilePath 'D:\sdvastrCopyFoldersGetValue.txt'
System.Object[]
```

, but not the expected array members which are:

```
Application
Data
Execution
```

If I am testing this HT/Array parameter passing/extraction between 2 scripts in plain PowerShell it all works as expected:

```
PS Z:\> $sdvastrCopyFolders.Length
3

PS Z:\> (,$sdvastrCopyFolders).GetValue(0)
Application
Data
Execution

PS Z:\> (,$sdvastrCopyFolders).GetValue(0).Item(2)
Execution
```

Comment: Could you tell me what you want to do? Could you tell me if you can run the script on-premise?

Comment: Well, execute an Azure Automation Account PowerShell runbook which shall execute a PowerShell script on an Azure Win VM. Must use Azure Automation; how to test this on-premise?

Comment: You can store PowerShell script you want to execute on Azure VM  on-premise then run the command in the PowerShell runbook on-premise.

Comment: Hi, the last days I was researching arrays again, running local tests with passing parameters using HT splatting when calling PS scripts directly ('&') - with success. However, running 'Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand' from my local machine gave the same result as when using Azure Automation: The remote script execution does not populate the array parameter; .Count=1, .GetValue(0) is the string "System.Object[]". I take in you new post below now, and come back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, when we run the command  `Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand`, the backend end will do some action to process the value of parameter which type is array.  Then we can not get the value in the script. But the backend end will not process the string type parameter. So I suggest you use the string parameter in the script. If one parameter needs some values, you can separate them with special characters such as `,`. For example:

My automation runbook:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $mycreds -Tenant e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb -ServicePrincipal 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
[string] $Filesharename = "test"
[string] $Folders ="test,test1"
$Params = @{Filesharename = $Filesharename;

                            Folders = $Folders;
    }


$groupName=' '
$vmName =' '
$path=' '

Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $groupName -Name $vmName -CommandId'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $path -Parameter $Params
```

Script :

```
  Param (
        [string] $Filesharename, 
        [string] $Folders 
        )


      $Folders | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\test.txt' -Append
      $test =  $Folders -split ','

      $test.GetType() | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\test.txt' -Append

      $test.Length | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\test.txt' -Append

      "-----------------------" | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\test.txt' -Append
      $test | foreach{$_} |  Out-File -FilePath 'C:\test.txt' -Append

      "-----------------------" | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\test.txt' -Append

      $test[0] | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\test.txt' -Append
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, and work done here! I understand that it seems not possible (for you or me) to get an array object propagated using "Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand" - what a crap by MS!!! (I wasted 1 week on this as I was trusting MS that this standard technique just must be working...) However, I will go on with your proposal of string-to-array - Thanks so much for this!!! I will mark your input as answer then despite me not believing that "Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand" cannot pass arrays. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could try converting array values to base64 format and pass the base64 values as parameter and you convert back from base64 to array

**convert Array to base64**

```
[Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($Array))
```

**convert from base64 to Array**

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($base64content))
```